# symfony2 - Defining Form as a Service result in error Could not load type "company"

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I´m straight following the Symfony2 book about forms,
right now i´m stuck at http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#defining-your-forms-as-services

i made it exact like in the Book, so i have an Entity called company and i created a Type for it:

```
namespace Core\CoreBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class CompanyType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', 'text')
            ->add('description', 'textarea')
            ->add('type', 'choice',array(  
                'choices' => array("farboo"=>"far","boo"=>"foo","bar"=>"barfoo","boofar"=>"foobar")
                ))
            ->add('save', 'submit');
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Core\CoreBundle\Entity\Company',
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'company';
    }
}
```

it perfectly works when using it like:

```
$company = new Company();
$form = $this->createForm(new CompanyType(),$company);
```

now i want to use it as a service, like described in symfony book, so i added this to my working services.yml:

```
core.form.type.company:
    class: Core\CoreBundle\Form\Type\CompanyType
    tags:
        - { name: form.company, alias: company }
```

Symfony book says "That's it! Now you can use your form type directly in a controller:"

but when i do so:

```
$company = new Company();
$form = $this->createForm('company',$company);
```

it throws exception:

```
"Could not load type "company"
```

what am i missing ? what´s the documentation missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your service definition is incorrect, it should be like this:

```
core.form.type.company:
    class: Core\CoreBundle\Form\Type\CompanyType
    tags:
        - { name: form.type, alias: company }
```

and use it like this:

```
$form = $this->createForm('company' /* <- alias */,$company);
```

Comment: This is it, Thank you so much i spent more than 2 hours not seeing that :D